# How to call an external xsd in an xml file?

Tags: java, xml, xsd

Hi all this is my xml file with xsd defined as internal to it

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<catalog xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
         xmlns:x="urn:book"> 
<!-- START OF SCHEMA -->
<xsd:schema targetNamespace="urn:book">
 <xsd:element name="book">
  <xsd:complexType>
    <xsd:sequence>
      <xsd:element name="author" type="xsd:string"/>
      <xsd:element name="title" type="xsd:string"/>
      <xsd:element name="genre" type="xsd:string"/>
      <xsd:element name="price" type="xsd:float"/>
      <xsd:element name="publish_date" type="xsd:date"/>
      <xsd:element name="description" type="xsd:string"/>
      <xsd:element name="number" type="xsd:integer"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
    <xsd:attribute name="id" type="xsd:string"/>
  </xsd:complexType>
 </xsd:element>
</xsd:schema>
<!-- END OF SCHEMA -->
   <x:book id="bk101">
      <author>Gambardella, Matthew</author>
      <title>XML Developer's Guide</title>
      <genre>Computer</genre>
      <price>44.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-10-01</publish_date>
      <description>An in-depth look at creating applications with
      XML.</description>
      <number>123.4 </number>
   </x:book>
</catalog>
```

i want to validate it in java and i have written below code for java and it is working perfectly for this xml.

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.transform.Source;
import javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource;
import javax.xml.validation.*;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
import javax.xml.xpath.*;
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;

public class TestValidation {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws SAXException, IOException, ParserConfigurationException, XPathExpressionException {
        XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
        NodeList nodes = (NodeList)xpath.evaluate("/*/*", new InputSource("E:\\abc.xml"), XPathConstants.NODESET);
        SchemaFactory factory = SchemaFactory.newInstance("http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema");
        Validator validator = factory.newSchema(new DOMSource(nodes.item(0))).newValidator();
        try {
            validator.validate(new DOMSource(nodes.item(1)));
            System.out.println("XML is valid.");
        }
        catch (SAXException ex) {
            System.out.println("XML is not valid because " + ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Now i want to define xsd as a seprate external file,i know how i can define that,can any one help me to find how to call that xsd from this xml and then do i need to make any changes in my java program

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you're following the example from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms759142%28v=vs.85%29.aspx. You can use its external-namespaced.xml and books2.xsd examples.

To validate the XML, use the answers from here:

[Validate XML against multiple arbitrary schemas](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7638457/116509)

or change your code to load the schema directly

```
  Validator validator = factory.newSchema(new StreamSource(
      TestValidation.class.getResourceAsStream("/books2.xsd"))).newValidator();
  try {
     validator.validate(new DOMSource(nodes.item(0)));
     System.out.println("XML is valid.");
  } catch (SAXException ex) {
     System.out.println("XML is not valid because " + ex.getMessage());
  }
```

Comment: i tried your solution on this employee.xsd                                                           <?xml version="1.0"?>
<schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
 <xsd:element name="p" type="xsd:string"/>
</xsd:schema>                                                                                                                                              AND                            this employee.xml but it is not working:::::::<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsd:p xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
 xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="employee.xsd">
Hello world!</p>

Comment: Although your code is working but the problem is that it is working IFF we only one node in the xml ,but if we dont know thw number of nodes in xml what should we do